# Processing to a Table in a python script tool not accessible via main model on Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I have a python script running in a main model that adds new fields to a table, runs some calculations etc. I have then tried to pass the final table as a parameter (ThemeIndicators_2) from the python script back into the main model so I can connect this to the 'Table to Excel'.

This works perfectly on my local machine but when I run it on Server as a GPTool I get the following error:

c:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisjobs\geoprocessing_dev\airogeoprofile_roi_gpserver\j225cda15bd37482c85f1f67aaddb3270\scratch\scratch.gdb\ThemeIndicators_2 does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (Table To Excel). Failed to execute (Model2). Failed to execute (GeoProfile_RoI_2).

It seems that the output from processing of table (ThemeIndicators_2) is not actually accessible in the scratch.gdb when the job is run on server. I have tried to set it to the scratch.gdb in the tool but it's not working. See last lines of python script below:

```
arcpy.DeleteField_management("ThemesIndicators_1", ["IndCode"])
OutTable = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB,"ThemesIndicators_2")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ThemesIndicators_1, OutTable)
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, "ThemesIndicators_2")
```

Comment: change your output to arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, OutTable)